# Как перенести шаблоны в bundle?

Tags: php, symfony2, symfony, twig, symfony3

сейчас путь прописываю так

```
{% extends ":AdminBundle:admin_base.html.twig" %}
```

это путь к каталогу

```
project/app/Resources/views/AdminBundle
```

А нужно как то прописать сюда

```
project/AdminBundle/Resources/views/admin_base.html.twig
```

Делаю так

```
{% extends "../admin_base.html.twig" %}
```

Получаю ошибку

```
Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (../admin_base.html.twig) in AppAdminBundle:Dashboard:main.html.twig at line 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем нужно было так, методом тыка подобрал.

```
{% extends "AppAdminBundle::admin_base.html.twig" %}
```